# why the Polymer custom data component can't send data

Tags: data-binding, polymer-2.x, custom-element

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
    <dom-module id="my-data">
      <script>
      ( function () {
        let dataValue = [
          {num: 'T001', status: '4', bground: 'num-sub'},
          {num: 'T002', status: '4', bground: 'num-sub'},
          {num: 'T003', status: '4', bground: 'num-sub'},
        ];
    class MyData extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-data'; }
      static get properties() { return {
        data: {
          type: Array,
          value: dataValue,
          readOnly: true,
          notify: true
        }
      }}
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyData.is, MyData);
      })();
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

I create a custom element my-data.html just like above.
Then the below is the usage in my-app.html.
My-data could be rendered but the my-app.html seems can not got my-data's info with `data: Array` property.

```
 <my-data data="{{data}}"></my-data>
    <dom-repeat items="{{data}}" as="entry">
      <template>
        <my-num entry="[[entry]]" ></my-num>
      </template>
    </dom-repeat>
</template>
  <script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          data: {
            type: Array,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
  </script>
```

Comment: Is this it? See https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat on how to use dom-repeat Polymer-managed template. See https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/zEzVLm for example.

Comment: If you're going to mutate the data of an array or object in `my-data` you have to notify the parent element. This can be handled using Polymer's `this.set(...)` in a manner such as `this.set('data', dataValue)`. See https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#set-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `my-data.html` and `my-num.html` in your `my-app.html` first.

Example:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-data.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-num.html">
```

Also, `id` name in `dom-module` of `my-num.html` should be `my-name` not `kvs-num`.

Import `dom-repeat` as well in your `my-app.html`.

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">
```

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JsXBo87yW9YDfc9o49c8?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, the my-data element could be rendered but other element still can't got the info from my-data's data property.

Comment: It depends how you are doing in `my-app.html`? That would be different question or edit your question and let me know.

Comment: You for to post the code or `my-num.html`. Did you import that file as well?

Comment: Yeah, I have import it .

Comment: Check my update answer now and Please delete your answer.

Comment: It works.Thanks for you kind advice and demo.It's great!

Comment: Sure your answer is great. Thanks.

Comment: @Jayly https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I'm sorry for that I miunderstood "accept answer".And now your right anwser has been marked useful.Thanks for your kind instruction.